# Derivative problem with give values

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hello please help me solve this, I really thought my asters for the last two parts were correct but apparently they were not. for part f i did 4 * -4 because that is what x * f'(x) would be equal to.. is that not what you do?! thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: For the derivative of $xf(x)$, use the *Product Rule*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))=f(x)+xf^{'}(x)$ by the product rule. Evaluated at $4$, this gives $2+4\times(-4)=2-16=\boxed{-14}$.

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f(x)}{x})=-\frac{1}{x^2}f(x)+\frac{f^{'}(x)}{x}$ by the product rule. Evaluated at $4$, this gives $-\frac{1}{16}2+\frac{-4}{4}=-\frac{1}{8}-1=\boxed{-\frac{9}{8}}$.

Comment: what rule can be used for part g? I'm assuming some sort of quotient rule, but the only one I have states d/dx(f(x) / g(x) = f'(x)g(x) - f(x) g'(x) / g(x)^2 and I don't really get how to use that since in part g the denominator is just x....?

Comment: @greta Let me add the answer.